# appending multiple similar functions to protoype

Tags: javascript, node.js, eval

I want to avoid redundant code for one of my projects, which is a [simple logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compact-log). This logger needs functions like *.alert, *.notice, etc. and I also decided to assign aliases to them (.alert = .al, etc.).

This leads to multiple similar functions, that only differ by one number, and the name.

```
Module.protoype.emergency = Module.prototype.em = function () {
    this.applyLogLevel(' + (i+1) + ', arguments);
}
```

As an attempt to make that code-base less redundant I created this "creator-function":

```
// create logging functions
var prototypeNames = [
    ['emergency', 'emer', 'mrgc', 'em'],
    ['alert', 'aler', 'alrt', 'al'],
    ['critical', 'crit', 'crtc', 'cr'],
    ['error', 'erro', 'rror', 'er'],
    ['warning', 'warn', 'wrng', 'wa'],
    ['notice', 'noti', 'notc', 'no'],
    ['info', 'in'],
    ['debug', 'debu', 'dbug', 'de']
];

for (var i = 0; i < prototypeNames.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < prototypeNames[i].length; j++) {
        Module.prototype[prototypeNames[i][j]] = Module.prototype.Namespace.prototype[prototypeNames[i][j]] = new Function ('this.applyLogLevel(' + (i+1) + ', arguments);');
    }
}
```

Now my Javascript linter tells me that `new Function()` is a form of `eval()`. Is there any other/better way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for:

```js
var prototypeNames = [
    ['emergency', 'emer', 'mrgc', 'em'],
    ['alert', 'aler', 'alrt', 'al'],
    ['critical', 'crit', 'crtc', 'cr'],
    ['error', 'erro', 'rror', 'er'],
    ['warning', 'warn', 'wrng', 'wa'],
    ['notice', 'noti', 'notc', 'no'],
    ['info', 'in'],
    ['debug', 'debu', 'dbug', 'de']
];

var Logger = {

    applyLogLevel: function(level, args) {
        document.write('log ' + level + ' ' + args[0] + '<br>');
    }

};

prototypeNames.forEach(function(names, level) {
    var fn = function() {
        this.applyLogLevel(level, arguments);
    };
    names.forEach(function(n) {
        Logger[n] = fn;
    });
});

Logger.emergency('oops')
Logger.warn('take care')
Logger.dbug('stop')
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `level+1`?

Comment: Yes it actually should. I just changed it in the solution I'm now using.

Answer (score 2):

you can probably replace

```
new Function ('this.applyLogLevel(' + (i+1) + ', arguments);');
```

by

```
(function(level) {
     return function() {
               this.applyLogLevel(level, arguments);
             }
     })(i+1);
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. It throws `Object has no method applyLogLevel`. Seems to operate outside of the prototype/class.

Comment: can you try the new version ? ; I had mishandled the scope in the first version

Comment: I really wish I could accept both questions, but as stackoverflow doesn't allow this I think I have to accept @georg's answer, because it includes a code snippet and therefore is much easier to understand for future visitors. Sorry for that, your help was really appreciated nevertheless.